# how to use IF logic to grab specific value

Tags: javascript

i'm new in javascript. i try to use if logic but i'm failed. My plan is if the zoom value is more than 5, the console.log show 'nice'. here are my code :

```
const zoom = mymap.setZoom(0);
if(zoom > 5) {
                console.log('nice')
            } else{
                console.log('not nice')
            }
```

the console.log always show 'not nice',
how i can fix it?

Comment: What is the value of `zoom`? Is it ever less than or equal to `5`?

Comment: What is `mymap`? What does `setZoom()` return?

Comment: Does `setZoom` return a value? Wouldn't you need `getZoom` instead?

Comment: the default code is const zoom = mymap.setZoom(13);
it is supposed the zoom level is = 13

Comment: i forgot to check via console.log the var zoom. shockingly the result is i {options: {…}, _handlers: Array(6), _layers: {…}, _zoomBoundLayers: {…}, _sizeChanged: false, …}
attributionControl: i {options: {…}, _attributions: {…}, _initHooksCalled: true, _map: i, _container: div.leaflet-control-attribution.leaflet-control}
boxZoom: i {_map: i, _container: div#mapid.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch.leaflet-fade-anim.leaflet-grab.leaflet-

Comment: i guess i need to get the specific zoom level value

Comment: You still haven't addressed the question of what *exactly* `mymap` is? What library are you using? Your question is severely lacking in these critical details necessary to give you anything concrete to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're working with [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), [`setZoom()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setZoom) doesn't return a value. As such, your variable `zoom` will always be `undefined`.

Instead, call [`getZoom()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.getZoom) to set the variable properly, which returns a `Number` indicating "the zoom of the map":

```
const zoom = mymap.getZoom();
if(zoom > 5) {
    console.log('nice')
} else{
    console.log('not nice')
}
```

Comment: you are right Mr. i'm working with Maps api i forgot to mention it. i already test your code and it works like charm. Thank you so much Mr. esqew for your guidance :-)